# Cast to NULL to unite tables (CH)

Tags: clickhouse

I want to `UNION` two tables with different number of columns. For example to unite in PostgreSQL I can run following query:

```
SELECT
id,
last_update_date,
metric_key,
metric_value
FROM schema.table1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
id,
last_update_date,
NULL::text as metric_key,
NULL::numeric as metric_value
FROM schema.table2
```

But in CH i cannot cast to NULL `NULL::text`, I receive an error:

`Cannot convert NULL to a non-nullable type: While processing CAST(NULL, 'text')`

I can run `NULL AS metric_key` but it has data type `Nothing`, but i want to specify data type, because Apache NiFi (using later to retrieve data from view) cannot read `Nothing` data type. How I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default types in CH are not Nullable

you need to use `Nullable` keyword

```sql
select
      NULL::Nullable(text),
      NULL::Nullable(int)
                             ;

SELECT
    CAST(NULL, 'Nullable(text)'),
    CAST(NULL, 'Nullable(int)')


┌─CAST(NULL, 'Nullable(text)')─┬─CAST(NULL, 'Nullable(int)')─┐
│ ᴺᵁᴸᴸ                         │                        ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │
└──────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────┘
```